# Primefaces dependent selectOneMenu and required="true"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

In my application I have three dropdown menu (`p:selectOneMenu`), say A, B, C. Among them two are dependent, say B and C. By changing the value of B I am dynamically loading values to C. Also there is a textbox. The value of the textbox is generating by ajax when the on-change event is firing from these three dropdowns.

Here is the xhtml:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="customerMenu" value="#{adminController.activityDTO.customerId}" required="true" label="Customer Name" style="width: 200px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{adminController.customers}" var="customer" itemLabel="#{customer.customerName}" itemValue="#{customer.customerId}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{adminController.generateActivityName}" update="activityId" />                       
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="activityTypeMenu" value="#{adminController.activityDTO.activityParentType}" required="true" label="Activity Type"
    style="width: 200px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{adminController.activityTypes}" var="activityType" itemLabel="#{activityType.parent}" itemValue="#{activityType.parent}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{adminController.updateDependentActivity}" update="activitySubType" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="activitySubTypeMenu" value="#{adminController.activityDTO.activitySubType}" required="true" label="Activity Sub Type"
    style="width: 200px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{adminController.activitySubTypes}" var="activityType" itemLabel="#{activityType.name}" itemValue="#{activityType.id}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{adminController.generateActivityId}" update="activityId" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:inputText id="activityId" autocomplete="off" readonly="true" value="#{adminController.activityDTO.activityId}"
    label="#{adbBundle['admin.addActivityPanel.addActivityTable.activityId']}" required="true" />
```

The `activityTypeMenu` and `activitySubTypeMenu` are dependent, by the selected value of the `activityTypeMenu` I am populating the `activitySubTypeMenu`.

Now the problems that I am facing is:

- Say I have select "External" and "Internal" in `activityTypeMenu` and default "Select One". If I choose "External" from `activityTypeMenu` the `activitySubTypeMenu` will have "Project" and "Service". But then if I choose the default "Select One" the `activitySubTypeMenu` is still holding the previously dynamically populated values. This is because the `required="true"` attribute resisting to fire the backend method from which I am loading the dynamic value.
- I have tried to set the `itemValue` of `<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />` to `#{null}` and then the backend method is firing on selecting the "Select one" option and I can set an empty list to `activitySubTypes` and this way the `activitySubTypeMenu` get empty. But in that case the `required="true"` is getting meaningless. I mean, I also have save button and on clicking that button without selecting any option (that is selecting "Select one") from `activityTypeMenu` and `activitySubTypeMenu` not throwing `ValidatorException` and the components are not getting styled by the error css class of Primefaces.
- Also if I don't set the `itemValue` of `<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />` to `#{null}` then on-changing to selected value to default option("Select one") does not clearing out the `activityId` `p:inputText`. If I use `#{null}` then I can get the backend method firing from which I can set the value of the textbox to empty.

How ca i solve this issues and get desired result. What I want are:

- If the option is set to "Select one" then the dependent menu will be empty and that of the textbox.
- I want to use the `required="true"` attribute.

Comment: Have you tried with `process="@this"` attribute in `p:ajax` tags? That avoids the validation of other form components, because only the component you're changing is processed by the JSF lifecycle. If not working, the easiest (but not best) way to get it work would be getting rid of `required="true"` attributes and validate the whole form entirely when it's sent. Good luck.

Comment: However I think already `p:ajax` defaults to `@this`.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, yes the `p:ajax` default value is `@this`

Comment: Try to use the `noSelectionOption="true"` flag on your `<f:selectItem/>`. It is a reserved flag that causes the runtime to evaluate your selection differently.

Comment: @kolossus according to http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4582 it has  bug with `noSelectionOption`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use EL in the `required` attribute. You can let the desired expression evaluate `true` only when a particular submit button is pressed, or when a particular component value is submitted (and thus by its client ID present in the request parameter map `#{param}`).

The following kickoff example should do what you need.

```
<p:selectOneMenu binding="#{menu1}" ... required="#{not empty param[submit.clientId]}">
    ...                       
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:selectOneMenu ... required="#{not empty param[menu1.clientId]}">
    ...                       
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:commandButton binding="#{submit}" ... />
```

This way, the 1st menu is only required when the form's main submit button is pressed (and thus not when event listeners are fired) and the 2nd menu is only required when the 1st menu has a value.

Comment: Do you have a full working example of that technique? Either BalusC or the OP (who marked it as the accepted answer). I added the bindings and changed my requireds but the 2nd menu still has a validation error.